# IIS 6 About 5% of request are very slow

Tags: performance, iis-6

We have a IIS 6 web server on Win2003

The avg requests/sec = 200
The avg cpu utilization = 30%
The memory 10% full
HDD avg time = 5%

I have turned on the logging to see time-taken for each request
and here what I see:
[image]

And here is the number of queries:

[image]

I have no idea why about 5% requests are working so slow. This is not only an application requests but static content requests too.